# Does Kendo UI PanelBar support HierarchicalDataSource?

Tags: hierarchy, kendo-ui, panelbar

Does Kendo UI PanelBar support HierarchicalDataSource?
I have code that works for Kendo TreeView but if instead of a TreeView I tell it to build a PanelBar, no control is constructed.

I am using 2012 Q3 -- Is this even supported or am I trying something that is not implemented?

```
 var ss = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({ data: panelBarSource });

 $('#panelBar').kendoPanelBar({
            dataSource: ss,
            dataValueField: "id",
            dataTextField: "name"
        });
```

`panelBarSource` resembles:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo UI PanelBar currently doesn't support hierarchical data source. Alternatively you can use a JSON object to initialize it. Check the docs for more information:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/panelbar/overview#initialize-a-panelbar-using-json-data-object

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing PanelBar does support hierarchical data model:

Please review [the following link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/panelbar/overview):

You'll find it about half way down...